# FirebaseMessaging IOS problem after deleteInstanceID

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an application where I have notifications.
If I log out and do nothing with FirebaseMessanging, the notifications continue to arrive.

With deleteInstanceID(), they stop arriving, but I don't subscribe to the channel again.
So if I logout and don't close the app, the notifications with the new token no longer arrive.

The problem is when use deleteIntanceID unregisters from remote notifications, and i need restore de notifications again.

This is only on IOS, it works fine on Android.

Please help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: firebaseMessaging.setAutoInitEnabled(true);
firebaseMessaging.deleteInstanceID();

After deleteInstanceID in IOS, when this in IOS unregisters from remote notifications. I need register again notification